# ¿Cómo puedo quedarme con aquellas filas que tienen las 24 horas de registros al completo en R?

Tags: r, rstudio, datetime, timeseries

Tengo un matriz que es una serie temporal con millones de observaciones y 6 variables, entre ellas el día, mes, año y hora. Lo que me gustaría hacer es quedarme solo con aquellos días que tengan 24 filas (24 horas de registros) porque al sumar el total diario no esté comparando días que no tengan el mismo número de registros. La estructura de la matriz es la siguiente:

| idta | day | month | year | hour | intensitat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 251 | 4 | 12 | 2015 | 1 | 224 |
| 251 | 4 | 12 | 2015 | 2 | 302 |
| 251 | 4 | 12 | 2015 | 3 | 565 |
| 251 | 4 | 12 | 2015 | 4 | 236 |
| 251 | 4 | 12 | 2015 | 5 | 592 |
| 251 | 4 | 12 | 2015 | 6 | 625 |
| 251 | 4 | 12 | 2015 | 7 | 635 |
| 251 | 4 | 12 | 2015 | 8 | 684 |
| 251 | 4 | 12 | 2015 | 9 | 521 |
| 251 | 4 | 12 | 2015 | 10 | 235 |

Muchas gracias de antenamano

Answer (score 0):

Lo anterior lo puedes hacer usando la librería `dplyr`, a través del siguiente código:

```
library(dplyr)

data_frame %>% 
  group_by(idta) %>% 
  mutate(num_filas = n()) %>% 
  filter(num_filas == 24)
```

Primero agrupas los datos por `id`, y luego cuentas el número de filas por `id`. Asumiendo que cada fila representa una hora única por id, este código debería servir.